# Trim leading/trailing whitespace from textarea using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, whitespace, trim, trailing

Following code is an example of text placed into a textarea from a database.

```
<textarea id="inputPane" cols="80" rows="40" class="pane">
<p>
    some text here...
</p>
  <p>
    more text here...
</p>
</textarea>
```

using jQuery's .trim what is the actual jquery code to remove all leading and trailing whitespace and have the textarea display very similar to below?

```
<textarea id="inputPane" cols="80" rows="40" class="pane">
    <p>some text here...</p>
    <p>more text here...</p>
</textarea>
```

I've worked on this for hours with no success trying varying combinations with .trim

```
$('#inputPane')jQuery.trim(string);
```

Comment: Note that the above is invalid HTML. You must escape `<` and `&` characters inside `<textarea>`, same as in other elements: `<textarea>&lt;p>some text&lt;/p></textarea>`. Browsers let you get away with the error, but only until your text contains the string `</textarea`...

Comment: If you have control over the server, and you're submitting it in a form, you could also just do the parsing on the server. It would probably be faster that way. In PHP, you can use the `DOMDocument` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
jQuery(function(​$) {
    var pane = $('#inputPane');
    pane.val($.trim(pane.val()).replace(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/g, '\n')
                               .replace(/(<[^\/][^>]*>)\s*/g, '$1')
                               .replace(/\s*(<\/[^>]+>)/g, '$1'));
});​
```

Which gives the result:

```
<p>some text here...</p>
<p>more text here...</p>
```

Though this may not be bulletproof, it should prove to be much faster/more efficient than creating elements from the HTML value of the textarea.

Comment: oh my gosh... this works exactly like we need it to! oh Thank you, Thank you Kevin. Life saver... i'm breathing again. ;)
You guys on stackoverflow are just amazing. i wish i could develop like you guys. i'm just a lowly veteran 10+ year front-end developer and designer that's stumbled into jQuery lately.
Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that this may not work exactly how you'd like with nested elements and such. How simple will your HTML be within this `<textarea>`?

Comment: will have many tables, ul/li's, etc. It's some pretty ugly code because it is actually email templates that we are pulling into our app and allowing admins to edit and save back to the database. So it's very ugly table-based code.

Comment: You may opt for a solution like patrick dw's, but any invalid HTML may not be correctly parsed and could cause errors.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var $input = $('#inputPane');

var $container = $('<div>').html( $input.val() );

$('*', $container).text( function(i,txt) {
    return $.trim( txt );
});

$input.val( $container.html() );
```

It turns the content of the `textarea` into elements, walks through them and trims the content, then inserts the resulting HTML back into the `textarea`.

---

**EDIT:** Modified to use `.val()` instead of `.text()` as noted by @bobince

Comment: @Marko - Thanks, but there could be flaws, though. Depends on the actual HTML vs. the desired output.

Comment: It should be `val()`, not `text()`, to get/set the content of a textarea (or other input). `text()` doesn't return the current value, it returns the initial value in the HTML markup, except in IE due to a bug. Avoid.

Comment: Thanks @bobince for the note. Updated. :o)

Comment: To cover any element within the input pane, use '#inputPane *' instead of '#inputPane > p'.

Comment: @Dave - You're right, but I wonder if you're looking at a cached version of this page, because I changed it quite a while ago. :o)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VNprH/)):

```
$('.pane').val(function(i,v){
    return v.replace(/\s+/g,' ').replace(/>(\s)</g,'>\n<');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.trim()` will remove leading and trailing whitespace from the entire string -- in this case, before the first `<p>` and after the last `</p>`. You want something more complex, which is to remove whitespace between certain tags. This is not necessarily easy, but could (perhaps!) be accomplished with a regular expression, for example:

```
// assuming val is the textarea contents:
val = val.replace(/>\s*</, '><').replace(/\s+$/, '');
```

**DISCLAIMER:** This was just quickly put together and may not cover every case.

Answer (score 1):

Get the value, trim the value, set the value:

```
var value = $('#inputPane').val();
value = $.trim(value);
$('#inputPane').val(value);
```

Or in one line:

```
$('#inputPane').val($.trim($('#inputPane').val()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to Trim leading/trailing whitespace from textarea. You need to code it in 1 line

Before:

```
<textarea id="inputPane" cols="80" rows="40" class="pane">
    <p>some text here...</p>
    <p>more text here...</p>
</textarea>
```

After:

```
<textarea id="inputPane" cols="80" rows="40" class="pane"><p>some text here...</p></textarea>
```