# Remove Space From Start and End From All Lines of TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am looking for remove white space from every line start and end. I am trying the code posted on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25305201/19253106)

```js
var lines = $("textarea[name=f01]") .val().split(/\n/);
var texts = [];
for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
    texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
  }
}
var n = texts.toString().split(",").join("\n");
$("textarea[name=f01]") .val(n);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="f01" id="40459045A">
 आज शिद्दत से 
दिल चाह रहा है,            
बंद आँखें खोलूं तो 
सामने तुम हो !!
</textarea>
```

But result is like this

[image: Result]

I think when , at the line end, its creating new empty line in it. I want result like

```
आज शिद्दत से
दिल चाह रहा है,
बंद आँखें खोलूं तो
सामने तुम हो !!
```

Let me know what I am missing in this. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `texts.toString().split(',')`? Just use `texts.join('\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you copied assumes that the text will not contain `,`. Converting an array to a string is equivalent to `array.join(',')`. Then it's splitting that with `.split(',')` to get the array elements. Buf if any of the strings contain a comma, this will split it into two lines in the result.

Just use `texts.join('\n')`. I have no idea why the other answer uses that.

```js
var lines = $("textarea[name=f01]") .val().split(/\n/);
var texts = [];
for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
    texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
  }
}
var n = texts.join("\n");
$("textarea[name=f01]") .val(n);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="f01" id="40459045A">
 आज शिद्दत से 
दिल चाह रहा है,            
बंद आँखें खोलूं तो 
सामने तुम हो !!
</textarea>
```

Comment: Its works like charm. I am waiting for accept the answer since its ask me to do after 2 minutes. :) Thanks a lot sir!